# referencing and labels

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox

I want to know how do you references well.

I use `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` but I can't willingly chose the number that will be displayed with the `\ref`.

I mean, how can I know what number will be written? Because I don't find it useful used in this way, I can't write theorem nr° `\ref`...

I saw that with the use of `ch:` or `sec:` you can gain control over this but it unfort. doesn't work for me...

waiting for your comments,

thank you :)

here is an example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\input{../configuration/configuration.tex}


\begin{document}

\chapter{lol}
See Theorem~\ref{abc} 
\chapter{lol}
\chapter{lol}


\begin{theoreme}{}
\end{theoreme}


\begin{theoreme}{}
\label{abc}
\end{theoreme}

\section{Something else} 

\section{Something else} 

\section{something} 

zzzz 
\section{Something else} 


\end{document}
```

it gives me 3... instead of the numbering of the theorem, which is 3.0.2

The code related to the theorem, done with `tcolorbox`:

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{theoreme}[2][]{%
    colback=white!95!roug,
    colframe=roug,
    colbacktitle=white!80!roug,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=Théorème~\thetcbcounter.\ #2,
    enhanced,
    before={\vspace{0.4cm}}, 
    after={\vspace{0.9cm}},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm, xshift=0.5cm},%
    #1% For possible options
}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. The whole point of `\label` and `\ref` is that you do not need to know the number while writing the document.

Comment: something like `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\section{something\label{abc}}

zzzz

\section{Something else}

See Section~\ref{abc}

\end{document}`

Comment: sorry if its not clear. I just want to write something like : check the theorem \ref{theoremblabla} and to have the counter of the theorem instead of the number that will be displayed

Comment: But that is exactly what `\ref` does. You presumably have a case where it is not making the number that you expect but if you do not show your code no one can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: The passage "... have the counter of the theorem instead of the number that will be displayed" is quite impenetrable. Please (re)explain what's going on in your document.

Comment: it's just I ask for an explanation of what does represent the number that is written on the latex paper (why do you have a 3 and not a 2), and how do you control it ? (with for example ch:)
I can't figure it out, even though I tried with many examples

Comment: the actual label has no effect `ch:` or `foobar` makes no difference, see the example I added above. If you get the wrong number then you put `\label` in the wring place but how can we tell you what to change if you show no example?

Comment: `can't willingly chose the number that will be displayed with the \ref` ... The label is something that is influenced by `\refstepcounter` of the underlying counter (unless using Black `\@currentlabel` Magic), so basically the number is fixed, if one does not changes the counter value or the output of `\the...`

Comment: What is inside this unavailable `configuration.tex`?

Comment: Oooo, this is interesting. I wonder what resides within `configuration.tex`... It's the crystal ball that will reveal all.

Comment: ooops I forgot to delete it hahaha I'm so clumsy sorry. Its the definition of the theorem box, do I need to add it ? it uses colorbox

Comment: `\ref{abc}` gives `2` for me, not `3`.

Comment: @MarineGalantin: Yes, you should provide the complete `configuration.tex`. And you mean `tcolorbox`, most likely. I suspect that you do not use `label=abc`, which is 'mandatory' for `tcolorbox` environments

Comment: is it sufficient ? my configuration file is really long with all the configuration of mathematical shortcuts, and maybe with 15 other boxes hahah

Comment: @MarineGalantin: If you would use the `cleveref` package you could even omit the tedious writing of `Theorem \ref...` all the time

Comment: I see you have an answer but next time please post an example that can be used to see the problem, the one above can only be used by you as it depends on `\input{../configuration/configuration.tex}`

Comment: but @DavidCarlisle I don't know what to do, when I write the whole thing no one is answering me, so i try to ask half questions to keep people's attention but meanwhile also have a solution. I see that now I can't ask anything more, but improving my previous question won't help me because people doesn't care about the special case thing I need. Here for example, I could have asked people how to make the labels works for EVERY boxes I have in my configuration.tex but I didn't because I thought I could do it myself after one answer, But the answer the other guy gave me isn't working at all!

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all, people could not answer your original question as it was impossible to understand even now it is not really possible to understand it. If you mean the current answer does not solve your problem then you should not have accepted it, people will not answer if it is marked as already solved.

Comment: @MarineGalantin: If you mean me with 'other guy' ... thank you very much ;-)  And hiding code in a file is **not** useful, since (La)TeX is a macro language that allows redefinition of basically anything. If some code in that `configuration` file screws up the referencing system this is not visible to us. Who ever gave that `configuration` stuff to you, it wasn't me, however

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The solution with `label=...` is the way to go with `tcolorbox` setup. That was the code added by the O.P. and I assumed that everything is setup that way.... and you know, we have enough users that add answers to questions which have an accepted answer just in order to get the tick ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry Christian I just wanted to write something quickly because I was writting you an email and also answering David. It was not turned in a bad way. I have a very bad english, my bad. I hope that now you have everything and you'll have the patience to take a look at the whole code... because yes it is really long for just configuration ( I find at least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suspected in a previous comment:

The environment is done with a regular `tcolorbox` code, which 'desparately' needs `label=` instead of `\label` somewhere later on.

See `\begin{theoreme}[label=abc]{...}` in the code.

However, I suggest to use a real `\newtcbtheorem` for such theorem entities.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\colorlet{roug}{red}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{theoreme}[2][]{%
    colback=white!95!roug,
    colframe=roug,
    colbacktitle=white!80!roug,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=Théorème~\thetcbcounter.\ #2,
    enhanced,
    before={\vspace{0.4cm}}, 
    after={\vspace{0.9cm}},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm, xshift=0.5cm},%
    #1% For possible options
}
%\input{../configuration/configuration.tex}

%\newtheorem{theoreme}{Le Theorème}


\begin{document}

\chapter{lol}
See Theorem~\ref{abc} 
\chapter{lol}
\chapter{lol}


\begin{theoreme}[label=other]{Foo}
\end{theoreme}


\begin{theoreme}[label=abc]{Foobar}
\end{theoreme}

\section{Something else} 

\section{Something else} 

\section{something} 

zzzz 
\section{Something else} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by \newtcbtheorem ? I only use what other guys on tex.stack gave me... I'm not that good in coding in Latex to succeed in writing those complicated environnements

Comment: @MarineGalantin: There is a `tcolorbox` manual, see page 338 of it. And I am answering a question of you the for the second time, although you still have not accepted my other answer, which is working. So I am one of the users that already helped you, but were at responsible for anything here.

Comment: but what did you add to my work ? only precising the label of the theorem like this ? [label=other]{Foo} because if I change only this in my document it does not work (still showing 3 alone ) and when I take the whole document it works...?

Comment: @MarineGalantin: That's the you way you have to do it with `tcolorbox` environments. As you can see the screenshot: It works.

Comment: :( for me it doesn't if I just change \begin{theoreme}[label=other]{Foo}
\end{theoreme}. Do you have any other idea? i m so sorry

Comment: @MarineGalantin if you edited your question so that it contained an example that got the wrong number then someone could tell you what you have done wrong, still have not provided an example that can be used to see any problem.